# Is there a way to functionally perform RedirectToAction in C# ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an existing ASP.NET core application where I need to block a set group of users from  actions on some of my controllers. I can do this on a per task basic but am looking for a way to function the entire block to avoid as much duplication as possible.

An example of how I did this for a Task is:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
  if(RestrictedUserCheckConditions) return RedirectToAction(nameof("RestrictionView"), "UserErrors");
  //continue with action for unrestricted users.
  ...
}
```

Is there a way I can function this to achive something like below to avoid too much duplication? Otherwise I have a lot of code to add to a lot of Tasks!

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
  RestrictedUserCheck();
  //continue with action for unrestricted users.
  ...
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about claim-based authorization? Then you can just add the claim for the specific users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Custom Authorize attribute to prevent user access the action method:

For example: create a CustomAuthorizeAttribute with the following code:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    //this method will access the block users, and transfer the data to the ClaimRequirementFilter
    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(string blockUser) : base(typeof(ClaimRequirementFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, blockUser) };
    }
}

public class ClaimRequirementFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    readonly Claim _claim; //we can get the block users from this property.

    public ClaimRequirementFilter(Claim claim)
    {
        _claim = claim;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        //query current user's claims and check whether current user is in the block user list
        var hasClaim = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.Any(c => c.Type == _claim.Type && _claim.Value.ToLower().Split(',').Contains(c.Value.ToLower()));

        //if current user is the block user, prevent user access the action method, and return a forbidresult.
        if (hasClaim)
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Then apply the above attribute on the action method:

```
[CustomAuthorize("bb@hotmail.com,cc@hotmail.com")]
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    return View();
}
```

the result as below:

[image]

[Note] In the above sample, we are using the [Asp.net core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), after login, it already adds the current user claims. If you don't use Asp.net core Identity, you have to add the claims to the HttpContext by yourself.

Besides, you can also use Policy based and Role based authorization to do it, refer the following links:

[Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Policy-Based And Role-Based Authorization In ASP.NET Core 3.0 Using Custom Handler](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/policy-based-role-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core/)